# Carthage static frameworks dSYMs

Tags: swift, cocoa, carthage, dsym, swift-framework

Per [Carthage docs](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/8481919f22b7ee4196f10827209c9d85bf22d469/Documentation/StaticFrameworks.md),

> It additionally makes sure that `xcodebuild` does not attempt to produce `dSYM` files for static frameworks, since this would cause a build failure otherwise

Does it mean that the final dynamic framework will have dSYMs for all statically linked dependencies OR I will not have such dSYMs at all?

Answer (score 2):

Finally found an answer on [Github](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1379#issuecomment-302250185)

> Crash symbolication seems to work fine with this approach, the symbols of the static framework just end up in the dSYM of the binary that they're linked into. The only bit of weirdness is that they'll be grouped under the name of whatever binary they're linked into in the crash report, e.g. `ReactiveCocoa` would show up within `<AppName>` in the stacktrace if `ReactiveCocoa` was statically linked into a binary named `<AppName>`.